# Snort causing DHCP ACK spam in VirtualBox internal network

Tags: virtualbox, dhcp, wireshark, snort

I have an internal network (10.10.0.0/24) in VirtualBox which has been configured with a DHCP server using VBoxManage. There are 3 VMs on the network, Ubuntu 16 (10.10.0.2 & 10.10.0.5), Ubuntu 18 (10.10.0.7) and Kali (10.10.0.3). The Ubuntu 16 VM has 2 network adapters and has snort installed configured in inline mode across the 2 adapters. The other 2 VMs just have a single network adapter each.

The plan is to add a snort rule to block ICMP traffic between Kali and Ubuntu 18 but at the moment the rules file is blank. However when snort starts running the network get spammed with DHCP ACK packets which originate from 10.10.0.1 which is not allocated to any of the VMs. When snort is stopped the packet spam also stops. I was wondering what might be causing this?

[image: Wireshark Screenshot]